# Recover Lost Voice Recording on EVO 4G

Tags: data-recovery, voice-recording

I was recording an hour-long meeting with the native voice recorder app on my EVO 4G. When I started the recording, I left it running in the background, hit the home screen, then shut the screen off. The meeting went slightly over an hour. I got a few email/sms notifications during the meeting, but none of them seemed to interrupt my recording.

Finally, when the meeting was wrapped up, I went to stop the recording, and noticed that it was indeed still recording (displaying the recording icon in the notification bar) when I went to stop it, but instead of accessing the Voice Recorder app via the notification bar, I flipped to the home screen that contained the app launch icon, and opened it that way. The next thing I knew, the voice recorder was set to record (it was no longer recording), and the last recording in the records was from two days ago.

I shut the phone off immediately, just in case. As I'm hoping that the recording still exists on the memory card or phone memory. Is there any hope for me of recovering this recording? Anyone ever had this happen to them, and did you have any success recovering the recording?

I'm at a loss for words to express how disappointed I am with my phone that this could have happened. You would think it would be constantly writing the recorded data to the device and have better error prevention, even if it may have lost a little of the recording at the end due to whatever error or bug caused this calamity, but I digress.

So what are my recovery options here?

Comment: I have not had this issue myself - but right now I am trying to replicate the issue and see what happens.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So I only tried to replicate the issue for a few minutes but even when I got the recorder to stop recording (opening the camera app forced the recorder to stop) it saved the recording.  I'm not sure if you already looked on the SD card but if you haven't try using [ES File Explorer](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop&feature=search_result) (or other [file explorer](https://market.android.com/search?q=file+explorer&c=apps)) and go to "sdcard/My Documents/My Recordings" ... thats where I found my recordings. Maybe its still there.

Comment: You're right. I just found the recording. I decided to take the SD card out completely and I loaded it up on my mac and I was able to find it in the exact directory you mentioned. So even though the Voice Recorder app didn't list it, it was indeed there. Thanks!

Comment: @purefusion Welcome - glad you found it.

Answer (score 2):

If the data still exists on the SD card, I've had some success with [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva). It might even be able to help if the file is on internal storage.

The question becomes, then, how to find the file?

Comment: Recuva is indeed a good app. I just recently used it to recover files after I lost a partition. I just hadn't tried it on a flash drive or SD card though.