# How to undelete an audio file from Asus fonepad 7 tablet?

Tags: data-recovery

A few days back I deleted one audio file accidentally. I created that file by recording using the application `Asus sound recorder`. That file had the extension of `.3gpp` or `.wav`.
I'm working on Android lolipop. 
Also, I would prefer a solution that doesn't require rooting my android device.

Comment: @eldarerathis I went through the link but couldn't get a solution I was looking for. I commented on that thread. The manual method it has mentioned, I can't use the `dd` command as my android tablet is mounted via `mtp`. Can you open this thread please!

Comment: @eldarerathis plz update & requesting you to reopen

Comment: If you want this to be reopened you're going to need to [edit] this to be much more specific as to what you've tried, where you're stuck, etc. Your situation is entirely generic at the moment, which is why it's a duplicate of another generic question. Did you try the other suggestions from the linked question? Did you look at other questions in the data-reovery tag, such as [Recover Lost Voice Recording on EVO 4G](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/6311/981) or [How to Restore Deleted / Formatted Files on HD Micro SD Card](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/7069/981)?

Comment: Further, without being willing to root, you're probably going to be out of luck. Any deep forensics will require block access to the device. You could use `dd` if you were willing to root, for example, by running it on your device directly.